# cannot receive json from server through php

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, post

i cannot  get the json from php on sever

the javascript code is:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "doingSQL.php",
            data: label,
            success: function(result) {
                $("#p").html("All my book: <br>"+ result);
                console.log(result);
                },
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(xhr){
                console.log("error");
               }
      });
```

the job of **doingSQL.php** is selecting bookName from SQL database and convert the data to json. it look like this:

```
   /* the server connecting code is omitted */

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $label = $_POST["label"];
    }
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE ower = '". $label."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            // output data of each row
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $Arr = array("id" => $row["book_id"],
                       "bookName" => $row["bookName"]);

                $bookDetail[] = array( "book".$i => $Arr);

        }}


        }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    $json = array("mybook" => $bookDetail);
    echo  json_encode($json);//  return json
```

but the result i got in the html console is "[ ]" or array[0].

the **json** is valid json format, it is look like:

```
{  
   "mybook":[  
      {  
         "book0":{  
            "id":"0",
            "bookName":"bookA"
         }
      },
      {  
         "book1":{  
            "id":"1",
            "bookName":"bookB"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

however, if the code is **outside** the SQL connection in **php**. the **json** returning will success.
  it is look like:

```
/* the server connecting code is omitted */

mysqli_close($conn);
// if outside the SQL connection

$ArrA = array("id" => "0", "bookName" => "bookA");
$ArrB = array("id" => "1", "bookName" => "bookB");

$bookDetail[] = array( "book0" => $ArrA);
$bookDetail[] = array( "book0" => $ArrB);

$json = array("mybook" => $bookDetail);
echo  json_encode($json);// return json success
```

any idea?

Comment: It looks like you are assigning the value returned from your query after you close the connection.

Comment: Also note that if this is production code, you're vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass your ajax `data` as :

```
data: {label:label}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **`data`** property of the `ajax settings` can be type of `PlainObject` or `String` or `Array`. For more reference see this [http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

So your javascript code would be like this :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "doingSQL.php",
  data: {label: label},
  success: function(result) {
    $("#p").html("All my book: <br>"+ result);
    console.log(result);
  },
  dataType: "json",
  error: function(xhr){
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

Comment: Why my php can still get the label value before editing the data: {label: label}? For example, I can use the label value to do sql selecting in php, but just cannot return to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `label` value in a variable. Now since on the PHP page you are using `$_POST['label']`, so pass the variable like this :

```
data: {label: label},
```

So your complete ajax code would look like :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "doingSQL.php",
  data: {label: label}, // changed here
  success: function(result) {
    $("#p").html("All my book: <br>"+ result);
    console.log(result);
  },
  dataType: "json",
  error: function(xhr){
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```